# How do I create a ParseUser using Auth0 in Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, auth0

Parse and Auth0 is very useful for efficiently creating a backend and authentication for different social logins. I was not able to find any information in the web specific to Android. Can anyone provide a tutorial for this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the logic I used to create a ParseUser after having a user sign-in using Auth0

1. Instantatiate an AuthenticationAPIClient
2. Retrieve the UserProfile by passing the idToken of the user
3. Run a ParseUser query to check if the user already exists in the ParseServer.
4. Log-in the user using ParseUser.becomeinBackground(user.getSessionToken...
5. If the user doesn't exist in the Parse Server, create a user using the information in UserProfile

   ```
   ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
   user.setUsername(payload.getEmail());
   user.setPassword(payload.getId());
   user.put("name", payload.getName());
   user.put("provider", "Auth0");
   user.setEmail(payload.getEmail());
   ```

This approach simplifies the OAuth process without having to use the different SDKs for several identity providers.

[Github Repository for example](https://github.com/iandjx/auth0_parse_demo)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the Parse User Interface? It's simply to utilise and accepts logins from Facebook and twitter. I don't think this uses Auth0 but can already handle two major social logins - what else do you require over these?

https://parseplatform.github.io//docs/android/guide/#user-interface

Comment: Google and Github login.